# Can't use Visualtreehelper in page loaded event don't get any event

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

When I use visualtreehelper in a page loaded event I don't get any element and get null exception but when use it on a ButtonClick got right result.

How to deal with it?

This is the function working fine on ButtonClick but not on Page_Loaded_Event

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj)
    where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I don't remeber, but let's see. Maybe that 'page loaded' does not guarantee that your **whole** UI is constructed? Maybe the Page is constructed and loaded to show some initial animations/etc and only after some time the actual contents are loaded?

[see this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.loaded)

quote:

> Instead, attach a Loaded event handler at the root of the **newly loaded page's content**, and perform any element manipulations, state changes, event wiring and so on in the Loaded event handler

Note they say "of the page's content", not "of the page". Try it.

If it does not help, you should be able to use Loaded of that Button you mentioned (or any other nearby control).

If even that does not help, you will need to check what templates are used by that page and when they are actually instantiated and use your ui-tree-scanner only after that point of time.